# Angular : Display data item stored in an array one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I've a simple situation, where I've a bunch of data stored in an array.
I want to display the array in html view, one by one, when the next/prev buttons are clicked.

I followed this : [How to show item from json Array one by one in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278454/how-to-show-item-from-json-array-one-by-one-in-angular-js)

However, My code doesn't seem to work.

Code :

```
/**
 * Created by PBC on 5/21/2016.
 */
var solver = angular.module('solver', []);
solver.controller('data', data);

function data($scope, $http){

    $scope.Type = "";
    $scope.qlist = [];
    $scope.alist = [];
    $scope.idx = 0;
    $scope.ans = "";
    $scope.q = "";

    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    };

    var data = $.param({
        _Down_Questions:localStorage.getItem('prb')
    });


    $http.post("../Php/download_questions.php", data, config).then
    (
        //Success Callback
        function (res) {
            $scope.Type = res.data.Type;
            if ($scope.Type == 'Objective'){
                for(var i = 0; i < res.data.Data.length; i++){
                    var data = {Q:res.data.Data[i]["Q"], A:res.data.Data[i]["A"]};
                    $scope.qlist[i] = data;
                }
            }
            else{
                for(var i = 0; i < res.data.Data.length; i++){
                    var data = {Q:res.data.Data[i]["Q"], A:res.data.Data[i]["A"], O:res.data.Data[i]["O"]};
                    $scope.qlist.push[i] = data;
                }
            }
        },
        //Error Callback
        function () {
            $scope.registrationResponse = "";
            swal("Request couldn't be sent!", "", "error");
        }
    );

    $scope.next = function () {
        if ($scope.idx < res.data.Data.length){
            $scope.alist[$scope.idx] = $scope.ans;
            $scope.idx += 1;
            $scope.ans = null;
        }
    };

    $scope.prev = function () {
        if ($scope.idx > 0){
            $scope.idx -= 1;
            ans = $scope.alist[$scope.idx];
        }
    };
}
```

using this, in the html as :

```
<div data-ng-controller="data">
        <div style="display: table;margin: 0 auto; width: 30%">
            <div class="row container" style="margin-top: 50%">
                <div class="col l12" data-ng-repeat="q in qlist track by $index" data-ng-show="$index == idx">
                    {{q[idx]["Q"]}}
                </div>
                <input placeholder="Answer" data-ng-model="ans" type="text" class="validate center">
                <div class="row" style="display: table;margin: 0 auto; width: 100%">
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" data-ng-click="next()" style="display: table;margin: 0 auto; width: 50%">Next</a><br>
                    <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" data-ng-click="prev()" style="display: table;margin: 0 auto; width: 50%">Previous</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: ng-resource ? I've ng-app="solver" declared at the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the mistakes:

1)

```
{{q[idx]["Q"]}}
```

should be

```
{{q["Q"]}}
```

2)

```
$scope.next = function () {
        if ($scope.idx < res.data.Data.length){
            $scope.alist[$scope.idx] = $scope.ans;
            $scope.idx += 1;
            $scope.ans = null;
        }
    };
```

Here, the condition was wrong :

it should be,

```
if ($scope.idx < $scope.qlist.length){
```